# how can i mix or and and in an if statement in bash?

Tags: bash

i have this function that accepts 3 parameters , ech one contain of 4 numbers and a capital letter for example : "1234A" 
and i want to print 1 if the second parameter is bigger than the third one and smaller than the first one ,
i wrote this function that i cutted the 4 numbers in a parameter for each parameter and the letter in diffrent paramater for each one and i began to compare
but the problem it print nothing !!

anyone know how to do things  in one if statement rather than two if statements ??

what i did :

```
function check {
    curr_letter=`echo "$1" | cut -c5` 
    min_letter=`echo "$3" | cut -c5`
    sm_letter=`echo "$2" | cut -c5`
    curr_nums=`echo "$1" | cut -c1-4`
    min_nums=`echo "$3" | cut -c1-4`
    sm_nums=`echo "$2" | cut -c1-4`
    if [[ sm_nums -eq curr_nums && sm_letter < curr_letter ]] ; then 
      if [[ sm_nums -eq min_nums && sm_letter > min_letter ]] ; then 
        echo 1
      fi
      if [[ sm_nums > min_nums ]] ; then
        echo 1
      fi
    fi

    if [[ sm_nums < curr_nums ]] ; then
      if [[ sm_nums -eq min_nums && sm_letter > min_letter ]] ; then 
        echo 1
      fi
      if [[ sm_nums > min_nums ]] ; then
        echo 1
      fi
    fi
}
```

i get nothing when i test this in bash , i get an empty line..
this is how i tested it :

```
p=`check "1617B" "1617A" "0000A"` echo $p
```

Comment: You aren't comparing variable values; you are comparing literal strings. `$sm_nums`, not `sm_nums`, etc.

Comment: but i thoght than in f statement we can do it without the $ :\

Comment: Also, assign and echo on two separate lines, or with a `;` between them. `var=value echo $var` will always be blank

Comment: when did i do something like this ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha In the line you used to test it

Comment: ok when i added $ it worked , but i still don't know why because i read that in an if statement we don't habe to put $

Comment: @newprogrammerha Only for arithmetic operators like `-eq`. [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically points out these and other problems

Comment: then how can i test it in the right way ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha assign and echo on two separate lines, or with a `;` between them. E.g. ``p=`check "1617B" "1617A" "0000A"`; echo $p``

Comment: ohh okkk thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the `$` in variable names within arithmetic context `((...))`.
Within `[[ ... ]]` you cannot omit it.

Instead of calling `echo ... | cut -c...`, you can easily extract substrings using Bash's very own syntax `{var:start:length}`.

Within a `[[ ... ]]` or `((...))`,
use `==` instead of `-eq`.

Note however that `<` and `>` operators sort lexicographically within a `[[ ... ]]`, but numerically in arithmetic context `((...))`.
Therefore the string-valued variables (named `*_letter` in your example) 
should be compared within `[[ ... ]]`, the numeric variables (named `*_nums` in your example) should be compared within `((...))`.

Like this:

```
function check() {
    curr_letter=${1:4:1}
    min_letter=${3:4:1}
    sm_letter=${2:4:1}
    curr_nums=${1:0:4}
    min_nums=${3:0:4}
    sm_nums=${2:0:4}

    if (( sm_nums == curr_nums )) && [[ $sm_letter < $curr_letter ]]; then 
        if (( sm_nums == min_nums )) && [[ $sm_letter > $min_letter ]] ; then 
            echo 1
        fi
        if (( sm_nums > min_nums )) ; then
            echo 1
        fi
    fi

    if (( sm_nums < curr_nums )) ; then
        if (( sm_nums == min_nums )) && [[ $sm_letter > $min_letter ]] ; then 
            echo 1
        fi
        if (( sm_nums > min_nums )) ; then
            echo 1
        fi
    fi
}
```

Lastly, instead of `` p=`check "1617B" "1617A" "0000A"`; echo $p ``,
better write like this:

```
echo $(check "1617B" "1617A" "0000A")
```

Comment: thank you so so much !! so basicly in bash wecan't do it in one if statement ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha can't do *what* in one if statement?

Comment: I would be very hesitant to use a variable named `sm_letter`or `curr_letter` inside `(( ... ))`; the names suggest they have alphabetic, not numeric, values.

Comment: @chepner indeed you're right. In the example those values are not numeric, and therefore comparing then with `<` in `((...))` would not actually work as expected. Thanks for spotting this, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
awk '$3 <= $2 && $2 <= $1 {print 1}'
```

or if you need a function

```
check() { awk '$3 <= $2 && $2 <= $1 {print 1}' <<< "$@"; }
```

or

```
check() { awk "BEGIN{if($3 <= $2 && $2 <= $1) print 1}"; }
```

Comment: because my professor asked us not to use awk which is a stupid thing to ask us to do .. to be honest

Comment: you can use the same comparison structure in `bash` itself.